# Redshift Spectrum external table is not showing in dbeaver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table created in Redshift Spectrum as an external table however that table does not show up in dbeaver for some reason. Is this a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can access external table in dbeaver using following query:

`select * from external_schema.external_table`

so point is add external schema name in select statement so you can query the data.